# Change the datatype for two columns of a pyspark dataframe after receiving json from Kafka server but am getting null values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am looking to change the "tweet_id" and "userID" of the pyspark dataframe I am constructed. I want the datatype for both to be of type **Integer**.

My code is below...

```
import findspark
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
import pyspark
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import os

os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.3.0 pyspark-shell'
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[2]").appName('LearningDataframeWork').getOrCreate()

schema = StructType([ 
        StructField("tweet_id", StringType(), True),
        StructField("tweet_text" , StringType(), True),
        StructField("userID" , StringType(), True),
        StructField("username" , StringType(), True),
        ])


df_tweets = spark.readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
    .option("subscribe", "TwitterTweets") \
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
    .load() \
    .select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"),schema).alias("converted")) \
    .select(col("converted.*"))

df = df_tweets.select('*')


query = df.writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .format("console") \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

I get the output...

```
|           tweet_id|          tweet_text|             userID|      username|
+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------+
|1545020704969695236|RT @dme_363: Wait...|1341441279905902593|      dme__363|
|1545020704927625216|RT @DeadlineDayLi...|          634939603|    mattlobooo|
|1545020703350685698|@10Junioor Ronald...|          126401539|       IGAOC12|
|1545020702000128003|RT @ManUtdMEN: Po...|1247589115010351109|       D_Nyeko|
|1545020700334981121|RT @AgoluaVictor:...| 757194951985856512| Iam_Bwoiralph|
|1545020699764576256|Pré-saison avec M...|         2255497760|     sunusport|
|1545020696283209728|RT @ManuelMenacho...|         2305097051|SoetanAdebare1|
|1545020695477997570|@Ayden__x Ronaldo...|         4121380654|      blaq_gem|
|1545020691220766720|RT @JamesSunday_:...| 757194951985856512| Iam_Bwoiralph|
|1545020689522073601|RT @CFCBlues_com:...|1542264394675109888|      CBrayzay|
```

the json **value** I extracted the data from is presented like below...

```
{"tweet_id": 15450003263664388, "tweet_text": "RT @Lordd: Who wears the Number 7 better??\\nLike for Kante, Retweet for Ronaldo\\n\\n||Ronaldo to Chelsea", "userID": 1196913590, "username": "davo_matsa"}'
```

I have tried using .withColumn() and change the the datatype of the column, the column's data type for tweet_id and userID does change to Integer but I get null fields.

```
df= df.withColumn("tweet_id_coverted", col("tweet_id").cast("Integer"))
```

It yielded me ...

```
+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------+-----------------+
|           tweet_id|          tweet_text|             userID|      username|tweet_id_coverted|
+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------+-----------------+
|1545020704969695236|RT @dme_363: Wait...|1341441279905902593|      dme__363|             null|
|1545020704927625216|RT @DeadlineDayLi...|          634939603|    mattlobooo|             null|
|1545020703350685698|@10Junioor Ronald...|          126401539|       IGAOC12|             null|
|1545020702000128003|RT @ManUtdMEN: Po...|1247589115010351109|       D_Nyeko|             null|
|1545020700334981121|RT @AgoluaVictor:...| 757194951985856512| Iam_Bwoiralph|             null|
|1545020699764576256|Pré-saison avec M...|         2255497760|     sunusport|             null|
|1545020696283209728|RT @ManuelMenacho...|         2305097051|SoetanAdebare1|             null|
|1545020695477997570|@Ayden__x Ronaldo...|         4121380654|      blaq_gem|             null|
|1545020691220766720|RT @JamesSunday_:...| 757194951985856512| Iam_Bwoiralph|             null|
|1545020689522073601|RT @CFCBlues_com:...|1542264394675109888|      CBrayzay|             null|
```

The main issue is the null fields I get when changing the datatype to **Integer**. As you can see from new column I tried creating.  Any help with a solution would be appreciated!

Comment: If you want it to be an int, why use `"tweet_id", StringType()` in the schema?

Comment: Changing it to IntegerType() also creates null values for tweet_id. I have tried this. I also tried leaving out the casting when using from_json(col("value")) but I get an error saying it "cannot resolve 'from_json(value)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires string type, however, 'value' is of binary type.;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
kafkaDf = spark.read.format("kafka")\
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")\
  .option("subscribe", 'TwitterTweets')\
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")\
  .load()

from pyspark.sql.functions import col, from_json
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType([
    StructField("tweet_id", LongType(), False),
    StructField("tweet_text", StringType(), False),
    StructField("userID", LongType(), False),
    StructField("username", StringType(), False),
])

parsed_df = kafkaDf.select(
    from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema).alias("value")
).select("value.*")
```

---

`parsed_df`

```
root
 |-- tweet_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- tweet_text: string (nullable = true)
 |-- userID: long (nullable = true)
 |-- username: string (nullable = true)

+-----------------+--------------------+----------+----------+
|         tweet_id|          tweet_text|    userID|  username|
+-----------------+--------------------+----------+----------+
|15450003263664388|RT @Lordd: Who we...|1196913590|davo_matsa|
+-----------------+--------------------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Amazing it works!!! Made things clearer!
My old code works too with LongType() as the dataType for the StructField. Glad to get a second opinion and that I overlooked that IntegerType wouldn't work on a number of that length.