# How to deserialize and read from a Kafka with PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I set up a Kafka Server publishing Messages that looks like this:

> "{\"sectionName\": \"World news\", \"webTitle\": \"Russia-Ukraine war live: Russian forces suffering heavy losses but neither side making progress, says UK\", \"webPublicationDate\": \"2023-11-18T10:24:06Z\", \"text\": \"test\"}"

I want to read the message in PySpark however, when I try this and print the result I only get Null Values

> +-----------+--------+------------------+----+
> |sectionName|webTitle|webPublicationDate|text|
> +-----------+--------+------------------+----+
> |NULL       |NULL    |NULL              |NULL|
> +-----------+--------+------------------+----+

I tried it with a String in the same format and it works as expected. But it won't work when I connect PySpark to Kafka. I have no idea what else I can do. I tought PySpark can deserialize it with ease.

See below for my code.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, from_json, expr, lit, get_json_object, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, TimestampType
import json

KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS = "kafka:9092"
KAFKA_TOPIC = "the_guardian"

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("read_from_kafka").getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")

def parse_json_fields(df):
    print('input df:')
    df.show(truncate=False)
    raw_df = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as json_data")

    print('raw_df:')
    raw_df.show(truncate=False)

    parsed_df = (
        raw_df
        .select(
            get_json_object(col("json_data"), "$.sectionName").alias("sectionName"),
            get_json_object(col("json_data"), "$.webTitle").alias("webTitle"),
            get_json_object(col("json_data"), "$.webPublicationDate").alias("webPublicationDate"),
            get_json_object(col("json_data"), "$.text").alias("text")
        )
    )

    return parsed_df


# -------hardcoded-------
hardcoded_df = spark.createDataFrame([("{\"sectionName\": \"World news\", \"webTitle\": \"world is a \\u2018delusion\\u2019\", \"webPublicationDate\": \"2023-12-14T08:24:51Z\", \"text\": \"xyz\"}",)], ["value"])
df_parsed = parse_json_fields(hardcoded_df)
print('hardcoded_df -> df_parsed:')
df_parsed.show(truncate=False)

# -------kafka-------
kafka_df = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS) \
    .option("subscribe", KAFKA_TOPIC) \
    .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
    .load()

df_parsed2 = parse_json_fields(kafka_df)
print('hardcoded_df -> df_parsed2:')
df_parsed2.show(truncate=False)

# Show the result
query = (
    df_parsed2
    .writeStream
    .outputMode("append")
    .format("console")
    .option("truncate", False)  # Display full content without truncation
    .start()
)
query.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Kafka isn't the issue here. Try again with just `json_df` and using `get_json_object`. Or, preferably, `from_json` function since you define `json_schema` but never use it

Comment: Thank you for your response! This doesn't seem to fix the issue. I tried the code you provided at a another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72901500/14997049
`parsed_df = df.select(
    from_json(col("value").cast("string"), json_schema).alias("value")
).select("value.*")`

Comment: btw I used `json_df` just as a test. I want to get the streaming data from kafka not from a single string

Comment: Did your testing work? The NULL columns just mean the schema is wrong. It's not specific to Kafka. That was my point

Comment: Can you post the output of updated code?